# imagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, xcode4.2

I've been looking and searching in the forum for a few days and I do not seem to understand how to resolve this problem I am currently facing while writing a small app for iPhone that take photos from the album and allows some minor picture editing using filters.

I am working with imagePickerController to select images from the photo album or from the camera.

The code that I am using was intended to work on a small jpg image "001.jpg"

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
[self.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"001.jpg"]];
}
```

and the relative adjustment slider would look like this:

```
(IBAction) sliderMoved:(id)sender;
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"001.jpg"]; ...
```

Since it all worked very well in my first phase and filters applies OK to the jpg, I moved on with implementing imagePickerController.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

So I was able to pick a photo from the album, show it on the UIImageView but the filters are still looking for 001.jpg so I've changed the name to:

```
        - (void)viewDidLoad {
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

and

```
- (IBAction) sliderMoved:(id)sender;
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]; ...
```

but it does not work, basically it crashes when i move the slide to apply the filter telling me that the location is invalid. Both didLoad and sliderMove were changed to reflect the picker image but neither one work.
I think i will have to rewrite the image, maybe smaller size and give it a name, that i where my understanding and knowledge really stops and need some help.

Thanks in advance and anything helps.

Comment: It should `crash`. As there's no file named `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` in your project. Instead of `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` you should give a `image-filename`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hemang! Make so much sense. This was my mistake and inexperience with the topic. I would like to ask you some help if you do not mind...in the regards of image-filename how do I find the image name of a picture in my UIImageView picked from photo album?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: [How to save images in photo Album](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum)

Afterwards, you will be able to read that image from your image library. Also, take into account that "UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage" is the key used to get an image from the info dictionary. Don't get confused with the image name, they are different things.

If you want to read/write images more easily from the library, my suggestion is to use [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009722) It helps a lot. For example, to write an image into your assets:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:finalImage.CGImage orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)finalImage.imageOrientation completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error ) {
    if(error){
        //Handle here your error
    }else{
        //Success! you saved your image!
        }
    }
 }];

//release your library
```

**Edit**

If you don't want to use assets, you can always make use of documents folder. Take a look a t this methods:

```
- (void)saveImage: (UIImage*)image
{
if (image != nil)
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
                   [NSString stringWithString: @"your_image_name.png"] ];
    NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

}

```
- (UIImage*)loadImage
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
                  [NSString stringWithString: @"your_image_name.png"] ];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
return image;
```

}

There are many workarounds for you. One would be, to save that image in your documents (with the method above), and work always with that copy in documents. But of course you have to be aware of disk usage, and keep in mind that a user won't be able to access to that image, since its in an internal folder and not in a camera roll.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. The image that I am attempting to process comes already from the library so in a sense i think it is already saved (not from this code). Since the filter needs a image name or an address in order to process it, how would you suggest to proceed?

Comment: I just added some code that could be helpful. Please check if it works with you. If you think is right, pelase, vote it and accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

If  you just want the original picked image there is one more delegate of `UIImagePickerController` class, it is

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
```

Use this delegate which gives the picked image, and also you can disable the editing of the image while its picked.